# C# WinForm DataGrid CellFormatting Does Not Work In Datasource Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Good day, I'm showing my queries from table in to the datagrid. But I'm having a problem with my codes. I tried to debug and add break point in my dgview_CellFormatting but the my code doesn't go to the event handler of cell formatting. I don't know why.

Here's my code. I put my datasource in my Form load

```
// dgv_details is supposed to be my datagrid view name.

DataTable table;

table = balreport.SelectDetails(belreport); // responsible for fetching data from the database.

this.dgv_details.DataSource = table;

this.dgv_details.Sort(this.dgv_details.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
// For sorting the data
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in this.dgv_details.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}

this.dgv_details.CellFormatting += dgv_details_CellFormatting;
```

And here's my dgv_details_CellFormatting event handler

```
 if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > 0)
 {
     if (dgv_salesdetails[0, e.RowIndex].Value == dgv_salesdetails[0, e.RowIndex - 1].Value)
     e.Value = "";
 }
```

The sorting is working properly, but the problem is, the e.Value should be hide.
The result should be something like this image

[image]

I really need a help.

Comment: do also `e.FormattingApplied = true;` in event handler

Comment: No, it gives me a lot of error in my dialog box. :/

Comment: your gird is filling or not

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
// dgv_details is supposed to be my datagrid view name.
this.dgv_details.CellFormatting += dgv_details_CellFormatting;
DataTable table;

table = balreport.SelectDetails(belreport); // responsible for fetching data from the database.

this.dgv_details.DataSource = table;

this.dgv_details.Sort(this.dgv_details.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
// For sorting the data
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in this.dgv_details.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

cause DataGrid CellFormatting event Does Work when datagrid fill.

Comment: Please help how can I fix this

Comment: i just check it its working. now clean solution and rebuild and try

Comment: go to properties and in event section use cellformating event and dont use this.dgv_details.CellFormatting += dgv_details_CellFormatting;

Comment: Can I see your screenshots? It's still doesn't work on my part :(

Comment: The problem is, the value in the cell one should be null because I included the e.Value = ""; if the value repeats, it should not be show as double format.